# Webpack-dev-server serves files from 'public' folder, but no files are saved in the folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, bundler

I'm using webpack-dev-server to serve my project files during development, and I have configured it to serve files from a 'public' folder. However, although the server is successfully serving the files, I've noticed that no files are actually saved in the 'public' folder. As a result, when I access the server, I can see the files being served, but the 'public' folder remains empty.

Here are some additional details about my configuration:

- I have a separate webpack configuration for development (webpack.config.development.js) and production (webpack.config.build.js).
- In the development configuration, I have specified the 'public' folder as the contentBase for webpack-dev-server.

I have verified that the necessary assets (JS, CSS, images) are correctly imported and used in my project's source files, and there are no errors or warnings related to file loading or asset processing.

What could be causing webpack-dev-server to serve the files from the 'public' folder without actually saving them in the folder? Am I missing any configuration or build step that is necessary to generate the files in the 'public' folder during development?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

### package.json file

```
{
  "name": "webpackplayground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "b:d": "nodemon app.js",
    "backend:build": "node app.js",
    "f:d": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.development.js",
    "frontend:build": "webpack --config webpack.config.build.js --mode production",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run backend:development\" \"npm run frontend:build\" --stats-error-details"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glslify-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.8.2",
    "include-media": "^2.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.5",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.7",
    "webpack": "^5.82.0",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prismicio/client": "^6.7.3",
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.9",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

---

### webpack.config.js file

```
import path from "path";
import webpack from "webpack";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const { DefinePlugin } = webpack;
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import ImageMinimizerPlugin from "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin";
import WebpackAssetsManifest from "webpack-assets-manifest";

const IS_DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev";
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

console.log(
  path.join(
    __dirname,
    "views ========================================================="
  )
);

const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, "app");
const dirShared = path.join(__dirname, "shared");
const dirStyles = path.join(__dirname, "styles");
const dirNode = "node_modules";

export default {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/index.js"),
    styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "styles/index.scss"),
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [dirApp, dirStyles, dirShared, dirNode],
  },

  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      IS_DEVELOPMENT,
    }),

    // new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    //   patterns: [
    //     {
    //       from: path.join(dirShared, "**/*"),
    //       to: "",
    //     },
    //   ],
    // }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),

    new WebpackAssetsManifest({
      output: "manifest.json", // file name for the manifest file
      publicPath: "/", // public path to prefix filenames with
      writeToDisk: true, // write manifest file to disk
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: "",
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(jpg|svg|png|gif|webp)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name(file) {
            return "[hash].[ext]";
          },
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },

      {
        test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
        loader: "raw-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },

      {
        test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
        loader: "glslify-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
          options: {
            plugins: [
              "imagemin-gifsicle",
              "imagemin-mozjpeg",
              "imagemin-pngquant",
              "imagemin-svgo",
            ],
          },
        },
        // Disable `loader`
        loader: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
};
```

---

### webpack.config.development.js

```
import { merge } from "webpack-merge";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
import config from "./webpack.config.js";

export default merge(config, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
});
```

---

### webpack.config.build.js

```
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from "clean-webpack-plugin";
import { merge } from "webpack-merge";
import config from "./webpack.config.js";
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export default merge(config, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
});
```

---

### app.js

```
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import errorHandler from "errorhandler";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as prismicH from "@prismicio/helpers";
import { client } from "./config/prismicConfig.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as prismic from "@prismicio/client";
import methodOverride from "method-override";
import logger from "morgan";

const __dirname = path.resolve();

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(errorHandler());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), {
    setHeaders: (res, filePath) => {
      if (filePath.endsWith(".woff") || filePath.endsWith(".woff2")) {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/font-woff");
      }
    },
  })
);

function linkResolver(doc) {
  if (doc.type === "product") {
    return `/detail/${doc.slug}`;
  } else if (doc.type === "about") {
    return "/about";
  } else if (doc.type === "collections") {
    return "/collections";
  }

  return "/";
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.ctx = {
    prismicH,
    linkResolver,
  };
  next();
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const meta = await client.getSingle("meta");
  const home = await client.getSingle("home");
  const preloader = await client.getSingle("preloader");
  const collections = await client.getAllByType("collection", {
    fetchLinks: "product.image",
  });
  res.render("pages/home", { home, preloader, meta, collections });
});

app.get("/collections", async (req, res) => {
  const meta = await client.getSingle("meta");
  const home = await client.getSingle("home");
  const preloader = await client.getSingle("preloader");
  const collections = await client.getAllByType("collection", {
    fetchLinks: "product.image",
  });
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(home, null, 2),
    " ------------------------------ "
  );
  res.render("pages/collections", {
    meta,
    home,
    collections,
    preloader,
  });
});

app.get("/about", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const about = await client.getSingle("about");
    const meta = await client.getSingle("meta");
    const preloader = await client.getSingle("preloader");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(meta, null, 2));
    res.render("pages/about", {
      about,
      meta,
      preloader,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});

app.get("/detail/:uid", async (req, res) => {
  const meta = await client.getSingle("meta");
  const preloader = await client.getSingle("preloader");
  const product = await client.getByUID("product", req.params.uid, {
    fetchLinks: "collection.title",
  });
  console.log(product.data);
  res.render("pages/detail", {
    meta,
    product,
    preloader,
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

---

---

---

**I am confused. According to my understanding, I am serving files using express but then I also have webpack. The webpack isn't configured properly is what I believe.What concept am I missing?**